# I tried insertion in BST tree using itteration but the output is incomplete. Where might be the problem?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I was doing insert operations in BST using iteration mechanism. I did in-order traversal using recursion for swift display of my tree and to know whether I am doing it right or wrong. However, the output is always 4 . I do not understand what might be the problem. Is my root not updating?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  
  typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
  } node;
  
  node *new(int data) {   //create node
    node *pw;
    pw = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
    pw->data = data;
    pw->left = NULL;
    pw->right= NULL;
    
    return pw;
  }
  
  node *insert(node *root, int data) {  //insert using iteration
    node *pr;
    pr = root;
    
    if (root==NULL)
        return new(data);
    
    while (pr!= NULL) {
        if(data< pr->data) {
            if(pr->left==NULL) {
                pr->data = data;
                pr=NULL;
              }
            else {
            pr= pr->left; 
          }
          } else if(data> pr->data) {
            if(pr->right==NULL) {
                    pr->data = data;
                    pr=NULL;
              }
            else {
            pr= pr->right; 
          }
      }
  }
  return pr;
}

 void inorder(node *root) {
  if (root != NULL) {
    // Traverse left
    inorder(root->left);

    // Traverse root
    printf("%d -> ", root->data);

    // Traverse right
    inorder(root->right);
  }
}
  
  void main(){
    node* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root,5);
    root = insert(root,6);
    root = insert(root,4);
    inorder(root);   //inorder traversal for displaying tree
  }
```

Comment: Don't you find it strange that `new` is only called when `root` is NULL. Don't you think that `new` needs to be called no matter where the node will be inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you are always changing the parent node's data instead of creating a new node to be the child of the parent node.
so instead of:

```
   if(pr->left==NULL){
        pr->data = data;
        pr=NULL;
      }
```

it needs to be:

```
       if(pr->left==NULL){
        pr->left = new(data);
        break; /*you have inserted the node, a break will stop the loop*/
      }
```

same change should be applied for the right if statement.

And further - `insert` has this return statement: `return pr` and that you save into `root` in the caller. However, `root` is only to be changed when `root` is NULL to start with. In other words: Returning `pr` is wrong.

Therefore do this change:

```
return pr; ---> return root;
```